# Ecmascript 6: how to implement proxy get() inheritase?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, prototypejs, es6-proxy

This is the code I tried to use (NOTICE: it is not a solution):

```
// define main object
class MyObject {}

// set proxy of Object's prototype as prototype of main object
Object.setPrototypeOf( MyObject.prototype, new Proxy( Object.prototype, {
    // implement new get behavior
    get( trapTarget, key, reciever ){
        // throw error if unexistansible variable is tried to be called
        if ( ! key in trapTarget )
            throw new SyntaxError( 'message' );

        return Reflect.get( trapTarget, key, reciever );
    }
}));

// define new child class
class MyChildObject extends MyObject {}

let child = new MyChildObject();
```

Due to MyObject.protototype proxy is referred to the Object's prototype, we can not get any properties from inherited instances.

How does my code works:

- when we'll call `child.unexistansibleVar` method `get()` will be catched by proxy
- I can not achieve `child.prototype`, due to proxie's `trapTarget` will always be `Object.prototype`, so all keys will be tried to be found there

How it should work:

- we call `child.unexistansibleVar`
- method get() will be catched by proxy
- proxy should achieve `child` and check `if ( ! key in child )`

My questions:

- is it possible to receive `child` in a proxy?
- are maybe any different ways to achieve my goal?

Comment: Proxies cause an indirection that has a great impact on performance. You should only use this technique in exceptional cases. Instead, apply a static type checker like flow to get type safe duck typing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to receive `child` in a proxy trap when we access `child.unexistansibleVar`?

Yes, you already do: it's the `receiver`. Check the property existence in that, not in the `trapTarget`, which in your example is always `Object.prototype`.

```
Object.setPrototypeOf( MyObject.prototype, new Proxy( Object.prototype, {
    get(target, key, receiver) {
        if (key in receiver) {
            return Reflect.get(target, key, receiver);
        } else {
            throw new SyntaxError( 'message' );
        }
    }
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class MainClass {
    constructor() {
        return new Proxy( this, {
            get( trapTarget, key, reciever ) {
                if ( ! ( key in trapTarget)  )
                    throw new SyntaxError( 'msg' );

                return Reflect.get( trapTarget, key );
            }
        });
    }
}

class ChildClass extends MainClass {}

let child = new ChildClass();

child.name = 'child object';

console.log( child.name );  // 'child object'
console.log( child.some );  // error 'msg'
```